# how can i handle no view found for id fragment

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-listfragment, runtimeexception

In my application I want to do the following , first I want to check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details fragment directly in the containing UI (it return false and I don't know why so I suppose it true any way ..) at the run time I have a run time 
exception, in the res file I have 2 folders for the layout the first with  the normal name layout with fragment_layout xml file  as the following :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/a_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <fragment class="com.example.tst_frag.TitlesFragment"
                    android:id="@+id/titles"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />



        </FrameLayout>
```

And the second folder which I  created it is the layout-land folder which has the the  fragment_layout xml flie with the following  code:

```
            <fragment class="com.example.tst_frag.TitlesFragment"
                    android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the logcat message:

```
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tst_frag/com.example.tst_frag.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080002 (com.example.tst_frag:id/details) for fragment DetailsFragment{45f4d648 #1 id=0x7f080002}
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        08-12 11:21:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can't you just call findViewById(R.id.Details); and embed fragment if result is not null?

Comment: which result,, i can't understand what do you talk about can talk in detail please